# Combinatorics - probability of picking 2 into different groups

Tags: combinatorics

So, we tried to solve this problem, but the "best" was 1/380 probability.

We have 20 footballers, we sort them randomly into 2 groups. What's the probability that Özil and Schweinsteiger will play against each other?

I tried to find a similar question, but I couldn't. We don't even know where to start. We don't really need the answer, but at least a way where to start, how to find out what it's the correct way to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it's roughly $\frac 12$...Pick the team for the first player, then the second either matches or doesn't with roughly equal odds. Slight problem in that the first player uses up one of the slots on his team.  Then the probability that the second player matches is actually $\frac 9{19}$, slightly less than $\frac 12$.

Comment: When you make the groups, is each one composed of $10$ people?  You don't say that, but it seems likely.  In that case lulu is correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry both teams are 10 men strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the team that Ozil plays on Team A, and the other team Team B.

There are 10 slots open on Team B, and 9 slots left on Team A;

so the probability that Schweinsteiger will end up on Team B is $\frac{10}{19}$.